# firebase Crashlytics libc.so

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

in firebase Crashlytics dashboard crashes have issues shows libc.so unknown with the help of logs I tried to reproduce the crashes cant able to do that anyone please explain what does it mean or any way to fix the crashes I have received more than 59 crash.

Firebase version - @react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.4.10[![enter image description here][1]][1]

List of packages I used below.

```
1.  "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",
2.  "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.7",
3.  "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.8",
4.  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.6",
5.  "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.4.10",
6.  "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^7.5.10",
7.  "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "^7.5.7",
8.  "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.9.1",
9.  "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^10.6.4",
10. "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.7",
11. "@sentry/react": "^5.24.2",
12. "@sentry/react-native": "^1.8.2",
13. "@sentry/tracing": "^5.24.2",
14. "apollo-boost": "0.4.3",
15. "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.5",
16. "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.7",
17. "apollo-utilities": "^1.3.3",
18. "axios": "^0.18.1",
19. "graphql": "^15.3.0",
20. "lodash": "^4.17.15",
21. "lottie-ios": "3.1.8",
22. "lottie-react-native": "3.5.0",
23. "moment": "^2.24.0",
24. "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
25. "react": "16.8.6",
26. "react-apollo": "^2.3.2",
27. "react-native": "^0.60.6",
28. "react-native-android-sms-listener": "^0.8.0",
29. "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
30. "react-native-branch": "^5.0.0",
31. "react-native-code-push": "6.1.1",
32. "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
33. "react-native-device-info": "^8.0.1",
34. "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^3.7.6",
35. "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
36. "react-native-fs": "2.14.1",
37. "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
38. "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.4",
39. "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
40. "react-native-pdf": "^6.0.0",
41. "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
42. "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
43. "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
44. "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
45. "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
46. "react-native-truecaller-sdk": "^1.0.4",
47. "react-native-video": "^5.0.2",
48. "react-native-webview": "^10.9.2",
49. "react-navigation": "^2.18.3",
50. "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
51. "redux": "^4.0.4",
52. "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
53. "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
54. "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.11.0",
55. "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.7"
```

Comment: Have you used any API filters in the Gradle file in the android project?

Comment: yes, iam using abi filters.

productFlavors {
        prod{
            dimension "abi"
            ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            applicationId 'com.appdemo’
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.appdemo"
        }
    }

Comment: if we use the ABI filters then it will filter the CPU architectures to allocate the so files.
So Except the Filter Architectures will not able to use the functionality so it will lead to crash

Comment: If I remove abi from Gradle. apk size gets increased. Any solution to reduce apk size?

Comment: Try to upload bundle instead of apk file and it is platform-specific so download size will be reduced. For example. if your bundle size is 90 then the app might be around 25 MB as per device architecture.